# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: MessageHeaders is immutable if I add header in the handler

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have following line in my handler:

```
headers.put(EMPTY_FILE, true);
```

It is a reason of:

```
2019-11-26 13:36:29.420 ERROR 2216 --- [sub-subscriber3] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@319058ce]; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: MessageHeaders is immutable, failedMessage=GenericMessage...
```

How could I fix it ?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48163978/immutable-message-in-spring-integration) will help you

Answer (score 4):

MessageHeaders is read-only. You can only copy exists headers to new map (include your own header too) and create NEW MessageHeader from this map.

Comment: How to replace old headers with new one?

Comment: `message = MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).setHeader(...).build();`

Comment: Yes, you need a MessageProcessor, or a HeaderEnricher that has a side effect. In my own application I had the same problem, ended up writing a `Consumer<HeaderEnricherSpec>` that adds a MessageProcessor that adds the header when it gets executed.