# MutableMessageBuilderFactory in Spring Integration

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I have a spring cloud stream consumer getting messages from Kafka. I want to modify the message headers, but currently the message I get is of type `GenericMessage`.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48163978/immutable-message-in-spring-integration) and [this code from spring integration core](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/message/MessageBuilderAtConfigTests.java) so I added to my configuration a bean of type `MutableMessageBuilderFactory` but I'm still getting the message as `GenericMessage`. Actually, the bean creating code doesn't even seem to get called, the `getMessageBuilderFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory)` in `IntegrationUtils` classs gets called multiple times and everytime `beanFactory.getBean("messageBuilderFactory", MessageBuilderFactory.class)` returns `DefaultMessageBuilderFactory`.

What might be the problem causing the factory I defined as bean not to work and the message to keep coming as `GenericMessage`?

Spring versions:

- spring-boot: 1.5.21
- spring-integration: 4.3.12

Answer (score 2):

Messages are immutable and there are many reasons for that, but it's out of scope of this question. What you can do is create a new Message in your handler and return it. If you want to copy most of the previous message and then modify the header you can do this:

```
Message resultMessage = MessageBuilder.fromMessage(sourceMessage).setHeader("myExistingHeader", "foo").build();
```

Comment: Yes, that possibility is known to me, I was hoping to avoid it but if there's no other way that's what I'll do. BTW - a nice post about it: https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2017/11/21/spring-integration-5-cloning-messages/